# c++ no suitable user-defined conversion from "myClass1" to "myClass1" exists

Tags: c++, visual-c++, vector

I'm very new to c++ and was really confused when this syntax error was highlighted by visual studio 2010. 
Definitions

```
class myClass1 {
    public: 
        myClass1();
}
class myClass2 {
    public:
        myClass2();
        void doSomething(myClass1 thing) {};
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    vector<myClass1> arr;
    arr.resize(1);
    arr[0] = myClass1();
    myClass2 c2 = myClass2();
    c2.doSomething(arr[0]); //this line is being highlighted as giving the error in the title
};
```

I'm just really confused as to what this means.

The syntax error is at the line that i commented and it gives the error "no suitable user-defined conversion from "myClass1" to "myClass1".

Edit: sorry about not making the question clear

Comment: Post the entire (compilable) example that is showing the problem, and also show what error the compiler is giving.  While there are some things that you are doing that are "unconventional", the posted code doesn't look problematic, and in fact, fixing the obvious compilation issues (no `;` after class definitions, no definitions of the functions declared), compiles as expected.

Comment: -1 "this line is being highlighted as giving the error in the title" is wrong. the title talks about `myClass`. the code on the other hand has `myClass1` and `myClass2`, but no `myClass`.

Comment: [You didn't post the code that has the error](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/775200a346d63b5b) so we can't help you. You should read how to make a [Minimal, Reproducable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

The myClass* classes contain nothing/do nothing so it's kind of hard to understand your purpose.
Your code won't compile because the constructors are not defined.
You should always provide a minimum of relevant information (and not much more) in your code pastes.

To declare an instance of a myClass2 object on the stack, simply do:

```
myClass2 c2;
```

The `doSomething` method uses a copy of myClass1, which is probably not what you want.
The copy constructor is not defined (but there is nothing to copy).
Plus the function does nothing...

Comment: Ah true, you just didn't define a copy constructor. You should use `void doSomething(myClass1 & thing);`

Comment: @cJZougloub You don't have to define a copy constructor in C++ - the compiler gives you a shallow copy constructor as a gift if you don't define one.

Comment: @IdanArye: The default copy constructor is not always shallow.

Comment: @BenVoigt True - it does call the member fields' copy constructors if they have any.